# Error message when open terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

This appears when I open the terminal:

```
bash: export: `=': not valid name
bash: export: `/home/(my account name)/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/(my account name)/bin': not valid name
```

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 i386, and I think I messed up with repositories or something.

Answer (score 5):

You have probably copy/pasted something in your `~/.bashrc` file.

`` bash: export: `=': not valid name `` probably means you used an `=` with spaces. Remove spaces around this to fix this.

`/home/(my account name)/bin` is wrong, you should replace (my account name) with your actual account name.

You can open your `.bashrc` by typing `gedit ~/.bashrc &` in your terminal or opening your home folder and choose *View* > *Show hidden files* and opening it from there.

If this doesn't fix it, could you add the contents of your `.bashrc` to your question?

Comment: Oh, it solved my problem.. Thanks a million! I've added space around the '='... Thanks..

PS. (my account name) thing, that was something what I've replaced from the terminal output, since that contained my personal info :) Thanks!

Comment: That was making me so mentally unstable seeing that error on top of every terminal. Thank you very much.