# Error message when opening the terminal "-bash: /usr/bin/tclsh: No such file or directory"

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using a Windows subsystem for linux Ubuntu terminal and every time I open a new terminal, I get this error message:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/tclsh: No such file or directory
-bash: export: _moduleraw: not a function
-bash: export: module: not a function
user@User-Laptop:~$
```

I checked my `.bashrc` file and it doesn't seem to have anything called `module` or `moduleraw`. (I did add some extra export statements for my code.)

The first error about `tclsh` is most likely me mistakenly entering `tclsh` instead of `tcsh` when trying to change to `tcsh`, but I still cannot find where that might be. Both my `.tcshrc` and `.cshrc` files are empty.

This question is very similar to [Error message when open terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102990/), but I checked my `.bashrc` file as suggested there for any reference to these errors and didn't find any.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: if you look at the end of `man bash` you can find all files bash uses.

Comment: Thanks, just checked. Of the files named there, towards the bottom under 'FILES' :

 /bin/bash, /etc/profile, /etc/bash.bashrc, /etc/bash.bash.logout, .bashrc, .bash_logout,
have text but no mention of 'module' or 'tclsh'.
 .bash_profile, .inputrc have no text.

Comment: it looks a lot like [Evaluation of modulecmd.tcl is not escaped properly](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/modules/+bug/1797345)

Comment: Default shell is set in `/etc/passwd`, you can change it with `chsh --shell /bin/bash <USER>`

Comment: I see, modulecmd.tcl comment is super helpful. Apparently, it was an error in environment-modules package. I installed 'tcl' based on this link with almost the same error and my error message went away. Thanks!!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52593010/errors-upon-opening-terminal-on-tclsh-and-module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks @bac0n

All I had to do was to `sudo apt install tcl` and this error doesn't show up any more. This was based on what I found on [Bug #1797345 "Evaluation of modulecmd.tcl is not escaped properl..." : Bugs : modules package : Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/modules/+bug/1797345) and [Errors upon opening terminal on tclsh and module - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52593010/)